# Gorm empty Find to Map

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm currently querying a MySql database in GO using gorm. I'm querying a table which i only know its name and nothing else. For this reason I return from the query `[]map[string]interface{}`, as suggested in gorm documentation (Find To Map, https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Find-To-Map).

I have the following problem: query returns right number of element,but are empty map (ex. `[map[] map[] map[] map[]]`). I don't know how to fix this problem, someone could help me to understand what's wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT

Code example:

```
db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "connection_to_my_db")
[...]
var results []map[string]interface{}
err := db.Table("MyTable").Where("condition = ?", id).Find(&results).Error
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
[...]
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: substantially, the code is the same of 'Find to Map' examples in documentation. I only set my table name. It returns the correct number of element, but they are empties.

Comment: Please can you post it - so we can see what is happening? This is a full working example of how to use the scan to map[string]interface method: https://play.golang.org/p/3JyqfRXwSji

Comment: Posted code is what i can show you, sorry.

Comment: can you show where you define the `results` variable?

Comment: Yes, sorry but i forgot to put varialble definition

Comment: Can you add `db.Debug()` and show the query log? Is it executing the SQL query? Is the `err` variable populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make sure you are using Gorm V2

Which is the git release tag 1.2. Gorm V1 doesn't support Find to Map. Check the instructions here on how to upgrade https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#How-To-Upgrade

```golang
var results []map[string]interface{}
db.Table("MyTable").Where("condition = ?","foo").Find(&results)
// This "pretty" prints it to the console
b, _:= json.MarshalIndent(results, "", "    ")
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: I tried the code but it returns null objects. I think the query doesn't scan correctly data into `[]map[string]interface{}` leaving empty objects. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the column types?

Comment: time.Time columns and numeric.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to try to upgrade Gorm. The way you open your db connection looks to be the old type (new ones require a config) and find to map was added in gorm v2 https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html (which is git tag v1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and my gorm is v1.9.x
but `Find` to struct will ok, to map will get map[] with right num of result

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31380856)